# What is the Best Way for an Uncircumcised Boy to Wipe After Peeing?

Tags: pre-schooler, education, potty-training

My son is four. His pediatrician said he should be wiping because he is not circumcised. What is the proper procedure for wiping a foreskin?

Comment: Have you already read https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/26758